# Ubuntu 22.04 mouse speed and trackpad scroll speed are off

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mouse, touchpad, ubuntu-22.04

How do I change this to match how it feels on windows? Mostly looking at the trackpad scroll speed as it is ridiculous when browsing firefox.

Curious if there's any new updates on how to fix this as everything I've seen is from years ago and saying imwheel/other might work or no good solution is out yet.

edit: also, how do i enable 2 finger swipe to go back in chrome, like in windows? ex: go to youtube, click on a video, don't like the video so 2 finger swipe to the right to go back.